# Create a data frame by comparing 2 data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I'm an absolute novice in Python,so pardon me if this is a simple one.All guidance will be much appreciated.

Dataset 1:
PlayerGame

```
Year-week-Name

2014-1-Dan
2014-1-James
2014-2-Dan
2014-2-James
```

Dataset 2 : Injury

```
Year-week--Name
2014-1-Dan
2014-1-James
2014-2-Dan
```

What I need is a 3rd dataset(or modified dataset1) that looks like this:

```
Year-week-Name-Dan-James
2014-1-Dan-1-1
2014-1-James-1-1
2014-2-Dan-1-0
2014-2-James-1-0
```

1. Should have columns named from a distinct list of player names from injury dataset added.
2. The Dan and James Column show 1 for all the weeks they were injured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm assuming you need to create a dataframe with year/week as index and columns with player names and values as their injury status for that week.

In that case this can be accomplished with a few steps:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

players=StringIO(u"""Year-Week-Name
2014-1-Dan
2014-1-James
2014-2-Dan
2014-2-James""")

df_players = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(players, sep="-", parse_dates=False)
df_players = df_players.reset_index()

injuries=StringIO(u"""Year-Week-Name
2014-1-Dan
2014-1-James
2014-2-Dan""")

df_injuries = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(injuries, sep="-", parse_dates=False)
df_injuries = df_injuries.reset_index()

player_names = df_players.Name.unique().tolist()

#Create new dataframe with all names as columns
df3 = df_players[['Year','Week','Name']]#.drop_duplicates()

for name in player_names:
    df3[name] = 0

# Set injury status from injuries dataframe
for i,r in df_injuries.iterrows():
        df3.loc[(df3['Year'] == r.Year) & (df3['Week'] == r.Week),r.Name] = 1

df3
```

Comment: I've updated to the format you originally looking for by just adding Name to index, there may be cleaner way of doing this though.

Comment: This works well, but I want to retain the all rows in df3.

Comment: My requirement has changed a little.This is what im trying to modify the code to get.Using  Nader Hisham output as reference.

What would I need to do if I wanted for Out[184] to have, Dan=1 for all Year Week combination where he was injured.So Dan values are currently(1,0,1,0), i would want it to be Dan(1,1,1,1) and James(1,1,0,0)

Comment: In that case I believe you can use transpose on the original edit (edited)

Comment: A transpose will not help here.Please look at the updated question.Pardon the naive skill.

Comment: @StevenSuting new update produces the output you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
# get dummy variables for injury
dummies_df = pd.get_dummies(injury.Name)

Out[176]:
Dan James
1   0
0   1
1   0

# then concatenate dummy data frame with injury data frame
injuries_with_dummies = pd.concat([injury , dummies_df] , axis = 1)

Out[178]:
Year    week    Name    Dan James
2014    1        Dan    1   0
2014    1        James  0   1
2014    2        Dan    1   0

final_with_nan = pd.merge( PlayerGame , injuries_with_dummies , on = ['Year' , 'week' , 'Name'] , how = 'left')


Out[181]:
Year    week    Name    Dan James
2014    1        Dan    1   0
2014    1        James  0   1
2014    2        Dan    1   0
2014    2        James  NaN NaN

final = final_with_nan.fillna(0)

Out[184]:
Year    week    Name    Dan James
2014    1        Dan    1   0
2014    1       James   0   1
2014    2       Dan     1   0
2014    2       James   0   0
```

Comment: Glad it helps :) , you can check the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: This works just great.What would I need to do if I wanted for Out[184] to have, Dan=1 for all Year Week combination where he was injured.So Dan values are currently(1,0,1,0), i would want it to be Dan(1,1,1,1) and James(1,1,0,0)